# What is the difference between validity and satisfiability?

Tags: logic

As the title says, What is the difference between validity and satisfiability?
Suppose I have a sentence `If the sun is made of blue cheese, then cats fly`.
How do I tell if its valid or satisfiable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mathematical logic, satisfiability and validity are elementary concepts of semantics.

> A formula is [*satisfiable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability) if it is possible to find an interpretation (model) that makes the formula true.
>
> A formula is [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)) if all interpretations make the formula true.

A formula $\varphi$ is *valid* iff its negation : $\lnot \varphi$ is *unsatisfiable*.

*Examples* from propositional logic :

> $\lnot p \lor p$ is *valid*;
>
> $p \lor q$ and $p \to q$ are examples of *satisfiable* formulas (but not valid);
>
> $p \land \lnot p$ is *unsatisfiable*.

---

The above concepts appy to *formulas*; a single statement of natural language is either *true* or *false*.

Specifically, the statement :

> "If the sun is made of blue cheese, then cats fly",

**if** we read the connective "if..., then ..." in the [truth-functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_function) way (i.e. as the [material conditiona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional)), is *true*, because the *antecedent* : "the sun is made of blue cheese" is *false*.

The sentence is an instance of the formula $p \to q$, that is satisfiable (but not valid).

Comment: I think the line "The above concepts appy to formulas; a single statement of natural language is either true or false." is misleading, since it's easy to read the emphasis as being on formulas vs. sentences (and of course a sentence is not true or false in the absence of an interpretation either); in fact, even the reference to natural language is misleading, since the real point is the role of "the world" as an *intended interpretation*.